# Creating a formset for an array of models

Tags: python, django

I have several views that display and save formsets for multiple model instances using modelformset_factory with a specific QuerySet and these work well.  Now I need to make a new page for a set of model instances, but I've got these instances in an array as I cannot create the list with a QuerySet.  In this case I don't think I can use modelformset_factory.

I'm guessing I have to use a regular formset with initial data extracted from the model instances, and then iterate over them individually when POST'd to save.  Is that the correct approach?  Is there a way to use the ModelForm I created for the other pages with a regular formset?  Or am I headed down the wrong path?